# Prolog Implementation of foldl1

Tags: prolog, fold, meta-predicate

I am trying to implement foldl1 in prolog without using build-in foldl predicate.

My code produce `Syntax error: Operator expected`:

```
foldl1(_, [E], E).

foldl1(Predicate, [X,Y|Z], Result) :-
  call(Predicate(X), Y, Ans),
  foldl1(Predicate, [Ans|Z], Result).
```

I expect:

```
?- foldl1(concat,['a','b','c','d'],X).
X = abcd.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Predicate(X)` is indeed invalid syntax as (in standard Prolog), the name of a compound term cannot be a variable. Use instead:

```
foldl1(_, [E], E).

foldl1(Predicate, [X,Y|Z], Result) :-
  call(Predicate, X, Y, Ans),
  foldl1(Predicate, [Ans|Z], Result).
```